# Group data in 2d array by one column, and use another column for summing

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sum, grouping

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (        
            [player_name] => AC
            [round] => 1              
            [winlose] => 10
            [game_title] => First
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [player_name] => M3
            [round] => 1              
            [winlose] => -50
            [game_title] => First 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [player_name] => M2
            [round] => 2             
            [winlose] => -50
            [game_title] => Second 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [player_name] => M1
            [round] => 2              
            [winlose] => -150
            [game_title] => Second 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [player_name] => M5
            [round] => 1              
            [winlose] => -50
            [game_title] => First 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [player_name] => M7
            [round] => 2              
            [winlose] => 50
            [game_title] => Second 
        )
)
```

**My code**

```
foreach ($getAllRound as $key => $value) {
    $negative = 0;
    $positive = 0;
   
    if (strpos($value['winlose'], '-') !== false) {
        $negative += $value['winlose'];
    } else{
        $positive += $value['winlose'];
    }
    
    $total = $positive + $negative;

    $dataa[$value['round']] = array(
                'round'    => $value['round'],
                'result'   => $value['game_title'],
                'positive' => $positive,
                'negative' => $negative,
                'total'    => $total,
            );
}
```

** final result should be**

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [round] => 1
                [positive] => 10
                [negative] => -100
                [total] => -90
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [round] => 2
                [positive] => 50
                [negative] => -200
                [total] => -150
            )
    )
```

Question: The above code unable to get the final result, by right it will loop the array and group as round then count total positive and negative value in every round and the total of the round. Does anyone able to help on this ya?

It's able to group as round 1 and 2, but the positive and negative value was wrong.

Comment: The `winlose` values are numeric, treat then like that and it should be fine

Comment: You can use `$value['winlose'] < 0` and `$value['winlose'] > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections)?

There are many functions you can use, such as `groupBy`, `map`, and `sum` in your case :

```
$data = collect($yourArray)
    ->groupBy('round')
    ->map(function($item, $round){
        $positive = collect($item)->map(function($item){ return $item['winlose'] > 0 ? $item['winlose'] : 0; })->sum();
        $negative = collect($item)->map(function($item){ return $item['winlose'] < 0 ? $item['winlose'] : 0; })->sum();

        return [
            'round' => $round,
            'positive' => $positive,
            'negative' => $negative,
            'total' => $positive + $negative
        ];
    });

dd($data->toArray());
```

Output :

```
array:2 [
  1 => array:4 [
    "round" => 1
    "positive" => 10
    "negative" => -100
    "total" => -90
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "round" => 2
    "positive" => 50
    "negative" => -200
    "total" => -150
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this should do it - https://3v4l.org/jeqdQ

```
$roundsExist = array();
$outputArray = array();
foreach($getAllRound as $playerRound){
    if(!in_array($playerRound['round'], $roundsExist)){
        $roundsExist[] = $playerRound['round'];
        $outputArray[$playerRound['round']]['round'] = array(
            'round' => $playerRound['round'],
            'positive' => 0,
            'negative' => 0,
            'total' => 0
        );

        if($playerRound['winlose'] <= 0){
            $outputArray[$playerRound['round']]['round']['negative'] += $playerRound['winlose'];
        }else{
            $outputArray[$playerRound['round']]['round']['positive'] += $playerRound['winlose'];
        }

        $outputArray[$playerRound['round']]['round']['total'] += $playerRound['winlose'];
    }
}
return $outputArray;
```

Comment: Edit was made to include link with a demo and also to fix a typo of switching $haystack and $needle in in_array()

Answer (score 1):

Declare reference variables containing zero-ed default values foreach newly encountered round value.  Then add its score to the appropriate category and the total.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0kZQu))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($getAllRound as ['round' => $r, 'winlose' => $wl]) {
    if (!isset($ref[$r])) {
        $ref[$r] = [
            'round' => $r,
            'positive' => 0,
            'negative' => 0,
            'total' => 0
        ];
        $result[] = &$ref[$r];
    }
    $key = $wl < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive';
    $ref[$r][$key] += $wl;
    $ref[$r]['total'] += $wl;
}

var_export($result);
```